# Get LDAP Attribute which contains an attribute object

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I added an LDAP entry which has an Attribute given by

```
BasicAttributes basicAttributes = new BasicAttributes();
BasicAttribute basicAttribute = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
basicAttribute.add("top");
basicAttribute.add("Adapter");
basicAttributes.put(basicAttribute);
basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("Name","testname"));
basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("Topic", "testtopic"));

if (locid.length != 0) {
basicAttribute = new BasicAttribute("LocID");

for (int i = 0; i < locationid.length; i++)
basicAttribute.add(locationid[i]);

basicAttributes.put(basicAttribute);
}

basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("Password", "passw"));
```

Now the password attribute is **SHA Hashed Password** .

But when I retrieve the Attributes using **ctx.getAttributes** like this

```
Attributes result = ctx.getAttributes(dn);
NamingEnumeration<?> nm = result.getAll();

while (nm.hasMore()) {
Attribute at = (Attribute) nm.next();
System.out.println(nm.next());
}
}
```

The output I get is

```
Password: [B@119cca4
Name: testname
Topic: testtopic
LocID: 
objectClass: top, Adapter
cn: test1234
```

How can I re-contruct the **password** to a String variable ?

EDIT : I tried this

```
while (nm.hasMore()) {
        Attribute at = (Attribute) nm.next();
        if ( at.getID().equals("Password"))
        {
            byte [] a = (byte[] )at.get();
            String b = new String(a);
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
```

Now it prints this - **{SSHA}AvvOJFnG2tjwNTGtDzDnubC/b2B1FbzP5S/LSQ==**

Now how do I get it to print just "passw" - the original password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retrieve the plain text password once it has been hashed; it is a one way hash.  If you **absolutely** need to get the plain text password back afterwards it would be advisable to store it in another attribute with a strong reversible encryption algorithm. And lock down access to the encrypted values. But only do this if you absolutely need the plain text password for some reason (i.e. you need to be able to post it for some legacy single sign on process).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wanted to show the password to the user who is viewing the LDAP entry. So i'l chuck it. And also, the entries already in LDAP has the password attribute as SHA Hashed password. But when I add a new entry with a password attribute like above, the password becomes SSHA Hashed password. You can see from the value I have written above. It is like '{SSHA}'.  It is due to the Salt value added to it. But I don't know where that value was added during the process. Can you give me some light on that ?